# Is this a bug in PyMC?

Tags: python, pymc

I am having some problems with PyMC, a python package for Monte Carlo simulations. I would like to know if this is a bug in PyMC or a problem from my part.

In this example we have a model with just two nodes: A,B. B is a categorical depending on A in the sense that the value of A is used to obtain (deterministically) the probabilities of B via a (deterministic) help function:

```
from pymc import Categorical, deterministic, MCMC
from pylab import hist, show

ITER=5000
BURN = 0
THETA = 0.5

A = Categorical('A', p=[0.5, 0.5])

@deterministic(plot=False)
def B_helper(a=A):
    if A == 1:
        return [THETA, 1 - THETA]
    else:
        return [1 - THETA, THETA]

B = Categorical('B', p = B_helper, value=0, observed=True)
M = MCMC([A,B])

M.sample(iter=ITER, burn=BURN, thin=1)

hist(M.trace('A')[:])
show()

print("\n The probability of A=0 equals: %f" \
    % ((M.trace('A')[:]==0).sum()/float(ITER-BURN)))
```

For `THETA = 0.5` One would expect complete symmetry. Bayes rule gives `P(A=0|B=0) = 0.5`. I obtain something far from it (it appears to converge to 1/3).

Now, if I change the above code by including a "dummy" first state with probability 0 in the nodes, I do get the expected result:

```
from pymc import Categorical, deterministic, MCMC
from pylab import hist, show

ITER=50000
BURN = 0
THETA = 0.5

A = Categorical('A', p=[0, 0.5, 0.5])  # Note the first state is "dummy" with zero probability.

@deterministic(plot=False)
def B_helper(a=A):
    if A == 0:
        return 0
    elif A == 1:
        return [0, THETA, 1 - THETA]  # Note the first state is "dummy" with zero probability.
    else:
        return [0, 1 - THETA, THETA]  # Note the first state is "dummy" with zero probability.

B = Categorical('B', p = B_helper, value=1, observed=True)
M = MCMC([A,B])

M.sample(iter=ITER, burn=BURN, thin=1)

hist(M.trace('A')[:])
show()

print("\n The probability of A=1 equals: %f" \
    % ((M.trace('A')[:]==0).sum()/float(ITER-BURN)))
```

Here state 0 are dummy states for A and B. And for `THETA = 0.5` I should get (due to symmetry of Bayes rule) `P(A=1|B=1) = 0.5`. I do get that. Furthermore, the position of the "dummy" state is important. If I set the dummy to be state 2 like in the code below I get wrong results again.

```
from pymc import Categorical, deterministic, MCMC
from pylab import hist, show

ITER=50000
BURN = 0
THETA = 0.5

A = Categorical('A', p=[0.5, 0.5, 0])  # Note I changed the order: dummy state is now the third.

@deterministic(plot=False)
def B_helper(a=A):
    if A == 0:
        return 0
    elif A == 1:
        return [THETA, 1 - THETA, 0]  # Note I changed the order: dummy state is now the third.
    else:
        return [1 - THETA, THETA, 0]  # Note I changed the order: dummy state is now the third.

B = Categorical('B', p = B_helper, value=1, observed=True)
M = MCMC([A,B])

M.sample(iter=ITER, burn=BURN, thin=1)

hist(M.trace('A')[:])
show()

print("\n The probability of A=1 equals: %f" \
    % ((M.trace('A')[:]==0).sum()/float(ITER-BURN)))
```

Either I am overseeing something subtle (hopefully not completely obvious) or categoricals are doing something strange in pymc (the logp values seems alright).

I've posted this in the github site but, understandably, it takes longer to obtain answers. If this is some problem from my part I guess I will know faster over here. Any help appreciated. Regards,

Comment: Can somone reproduce this?

Comment: You can follow the issue here: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/16